# How to export the VS2010 command line build/compile parameters

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Given a C# solution with VS2010, how can I export the current build/compile settings so that I can build/compile it with command line.

Comment: Question is how you are going to build with command line. According to that, answer can be different, I think.

Comment: If you mean via "csc"; note that while you can get the IDE to emit this (I'm still trying to dig out how), it is a white lie: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ed_maurer/archive/2008/06/11/a-tale-of-two-compilers.aspx

Comment: Copy it from the Output window :)

Answer (score 4):

Have you customized any build options? You can use msbuild from the Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt.

```
msbuild YourSolution.sln
```

You can also specify various solution properties, such as Configuration.

```
msbuild YourSolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean via "csc"; bring up the Output window; build, and change it to Build; now look for `csc` in that window. For example:

```
Task "Csc" (TaskId:21)
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:x86 /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\x86\Debug\ConsoleApplication26.exe /target:exe Program.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\Users\mgravell\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client.AssemblyAttributes.cs" (TaskId:21)
```

or (at a different output-level):

```
CoreCompile:
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:x86 /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\x86\Debug\ConsoleApplication26.exe /target:exe Program.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\Users\mgravell\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
```

[image]

But note that [the command it displays *is a white lie*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ed_maurer/archive/2008/06/11/a-tale-of-two-compilers.aspx).

Comment: I don't see there is a build window

Comment: @q0987 the **output** window, then select the "build" option *in* that window